# List index out of range in nested for loop

Tags: python, list, wordle-game

I am making an algorithm to solve wordles. I get a list index out of range when it comes to around line 47 (for x in range (0,5) when I append words that don't have the correct character that matches a "green" character (shortened to g).

```
my_file = open("valid-wordle-words.txt", "r")
data = my_file.read()

five_letter_words = data.split("\n")

my_file.close()

word_answer = ["t", "r", "e", "a", "d"]
word_colors = []

yellow = []

black = []

words_to_remove = []




    
for c in word_answer:
    color = input("Color:")
    word_colors.append(color)
        
    if color == 'y':
        yellow.append(c)
            
    if color == 'b':
        black.append(c)

for w in five_letter_words:
        
    for c in black:
        if c in w:
            words_to_remove.append(w)
            break

for w in five_letter_words:
    
    for c in yellow:
        if c not in w:
            words_to_remove.append(w)
            break

for w in five_letter_words:
    word = []
    for c in w:
        word.append(c)
    for x in range (0,5):
        if word[x] == word_answer[x] and word_colors[x] != "g":
            words_to_remove.append(w)
            break

five_letter_words = [i for i in five_letter_words if i not in words_to_remove]
```

Comment: Can you include a stack backtrace?

Comment: I solved this! It was supposed to be if word[x] != word_answer[x] and word_colors[x] == "g": ! Not sure why it breaks with the original statement but it works now.

Comment: @StellaKozloski, if you found the right fix, please write a regular answer. An answer will  help the whole community, a comment... not so much